# Getting error in gamemaker studio 2 when using function ord

Tags: game-maker

I'm getting this error:

```
FATAL ERROR in
action number 1
of  Step Event0
for object obj_player2:

Variable obj_player2.D(100004, -2147483648) not set before reading it.
 at gml_Object_obj_player2_Step_0 (line 5) - var xadd = keyboard_check(ord(D))- keyboard_check(ord(A));
```

I followed a tutorial on youtube, I changed the vk_left etc. to ord(a) instead since I need 2 players at the same time.

Comment: Have you tried reading the error? `Variable obj_player2.D not set before reading it`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put "" around strings. So ord("A").